What language are the elves actually speaking to each other when we hear them in English?
In Season 2 of The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power, we mostly hear the elves in Middle-earth speaking English to each other but sometimes code-switching to Sindarin for emphasis or in moments of emotion. What language are they supposed to be speaking in-universe when we hear them in English?
In the first episode of Season 2, there's a scene where Galadriel, Elrond, and Gil-galad are conversing. While most of their dialogue is in English, they occasionally code-switch to Sindarin. The subtitles note these shifts, particularly when Gil-galad "exclaims in Sindarin." The subtitles also indicate when they switch back to English by stating "in English."
This code-switching got me thinking: Are we meant to understand that they're actually speaking Westron (the "Common Speech" of Middle-earth, which is represented as English) when we hear English? That seems odd, given that Sindarin is the primary language of the elves in Middle-earth. Wouldn't it make more sense for the elves to speak Sindarin consistently, without code-switching to Westron among themselves?
On the other hand, if we're meant to assume they're speaking Sindarin the whole time, why do the subtitles explicitly point out when they switch to Sindarin (which implies they weren't using it before) and then back to English?

Translation Convention on TVTropes (warning: TVTropes link)

@Kenster If we're meant to assume they're speaking Sindarin the whole time, why do the subtitles explicitly point out when they switch to Sindarin (which implies they weren't using it before)? This seems to contradict the Translation Convention trope.

the subtitles simply state the language origin ... they do not imply anything about the language origin of speech that is not covered by the subtitle

They probably periodically switch back to elvish... To remind the audience that they're elves

The subtitles are primarily for those unable to hear the use of Sindarin vs English by the actors. They are out-of-universe descriptions of dialogue. (I'm assuming the subtitles also translate, rather than transliterate, Sindarin to English.)

In the books, Westron did not become the Lingua Franca until much later in the Third Age. Even in the TA the Elves spoke to each other in Elvish. There was no other lingua franca than Sindarin the Elves could turn to in the Second Age.

For season 1, I would have said they were speaking Sindarin among themselves, and when switching to Quenya it was not translated. I believe James Tauber semi-confirmed this with a member of the (secret) translation team. But now in season 2 we have untranslated Quenta (Gil-galad's song) and Sindarin (eg Galadriel talking to Gil-galad). So it seems like a soft reboot of the 'translation' conceit for the second season.

@Eugene the show does seem to imply a lingua franca of some sort, given that the proto-hobbits can speak to people in Rhun. What that is, in the absence of any large superpower (especially the RoP version which doesn't even have Numenorean colonies), is unclear (that's RoP for you etc etc etc)
